# Vitest - TypeError: _ctx.$t is not a function

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-i18n, vitest

I have a vue 3 project with typescript.
I used vue-i18n for localization and for test, I use vitest.
When I want to render components in test that have i18n, got this error:

How can I fix it?

```
TypeError: _ctx.$t is not a function
 ❯ Proxy._sfc_render src/components/loader/AppLoader.vue:11:52
      9|     </div>
     10|     <div v-else-if="isEmpty">
     11|       <span class="text-gray-500 text-lg block">{{ $t('message.empty') }}</span>
       |                                                    ^
     12|     </div>
     13|   </div
```